# How can I make an app fullscreen and get rid of top status bar + bottom gesture?

Tags: java, android, fullscreen, statusbar, gesture

I have already changed my app layout and theme into fullscreen, but the problem is still after hiding the status bar it's still there with blank black color and even bottom of the screen (gesture) is taking some space and show blank white color behind it. So is there any way to make an app fullscreen and get rid of top status bar + bottom gesture? But if the user drags over the top or bottom the gesture and status bar shows up?

Just for more information I use (Xiaomi redmi note 8 pro) Android 11 with xiaomi official firmware.
[I'll share a photo here so you can better understand what I'm talking about and what I want to hide in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZRwD.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i used this code for make everything hidden .
now the problem solved .
here is the code .

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus)
        {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
```